# Getting GCM REG ID From a non activity class

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I built a class "Profile" which is not extends activity class.
How can i get the GCM Registration id in that class. I have already get the GCM registration Id in my mainActivity class.
My code is below

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
public class Profile extends Fragment implements Common{
Context context;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context); 
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
    Log.v("GCM ID", "GCM ID is " + regId);
    }
}
```

I have written some code inside the onCreatview which is working fine but after this code (GCMRegistrar) my app is crash.

Please Help me out.

The error is

```
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at        com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.getGCMPreferences(GCMRegistrar.java:502)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at    com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(GCMRegistrar.java:330)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at com.afixi.aap_leader_profile.Profile.onCreateView(Profile.java:225)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
04-02 18:45:40.969: E/AndroidRuntime(8778):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `context` variable is null. You never initialize it, but pass it to other methods. That's the cause for the `NullPointerException`. You can use the fragment's activity as context :

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
public class Profile extends Fragment implements Common{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getActivity());
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getActivity()); 
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getActivity());
    Log.v("GCM ID", "GCM ID is " + regId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GCMRegistrar is deprecated. Use the GCM API.

But if you wish to persist using it, show your LogCat. I suppose it's something with dependencies or threads, as GCMRegistrar is asynchronous.